# What should the specs be for a AWS VM to install and run a Metabase JAR app

Tags: amazon-web-services, jvm, ubuntu-16.04, executable-jar, metabase

Im planning an installation of this version of Metabase:

```
https://www.metabase.com/docs/v0.35.4/
```

I dont see any docs on what are the minimum requirements for RAM, CPU etc
Im only planning to run Metabase on this instance for a user base of 100 people

What specs should I choose for a VM?

Answer (score 0):

[Their documentation](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-metabase-on-elastic-beanstalk.html#configuration-details) recommends `t2.small` instance type:

> Instance type (Instances block) is for picking the size of AWS instance you want to run. Any size is fine but we recommend `t2.small` for most uses.

According to [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), `t2.small` instances have 1 vCPU and 2 GB RAM.